# type '_AnimatedEvaluation<Color?>' is not a subtype of type 'Animation<Color>' in type cast

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I was creating a simple animating heart. It was working fine without null safety. When I try to change it in null safety. I got this issue.

```
class _HeartState extends State<Heart> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  late AnimationController _controller;
  late Animation<Color?> _colorAnimation;
  late Animation<double> _sizeAnimation;
  late Animation<double> _curve;

  bool isFav = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = AnimationController(
      duration: Duration(
        milliseconds: 500,
      ),
      vsync: this,
    );

    _curve = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: _controller,
      curve: Curves.slowMiddle,
    );

    _colorAnimation = ColorTween(begin: Colors.grey[400], end: Colors.red)
        .animate(_curve) as Animation<Color>;
```

Comment: you need: `as Animation<Color?>`

Comment: or just remove `as Animation<Color>`

Comment: oh..how I miss that one.